# OpenJpa in Apache Geronimo 3.0

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, openjpa, geronimo

I have a newbie question, so I hope you can help. 
Currently as ORM tool I am using OpenJPA 2.2.1 .

MY CUrrent persistence UNit:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="FleaCircus" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>Flea Circus</description>
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>FleaCircusOracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ApplicationItem</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.FleaResult</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.FleaResultType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemGroup</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemTypeAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemTypeOperationAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Operation</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.OperationAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.OperationType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Role</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.UserAccount</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Measurement</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.MeasurementType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.MeasurementAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.MeasurementAttributeType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Fleet</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="validate" />
            <property
                name="openjpa.Compatibility.CheckDatabaseForCascadePersistToDetachedEntity"
                value="true" />
              <!--<property name="openjpa.Log"
                value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


    <persistence-unit name="FleaCircusLocal" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>Flea Circus</description>
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>FleaCircusOracleDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ApplicationItem</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.FleaResult</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.FleaResultType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemGroup</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemTypeAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.ItemTypeOperationAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Operation</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.OperationAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.OperationType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Role</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.UserAccount</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Measurement</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.MeasurementType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.MeasurementAttribute</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.MeasurementAttributeType</class>
        <class>de.carmedialab.db.entities.Fleet</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="validate" />
            <property
                name="openjpa.Compatibility.CheckDatabaseForCascadePersistToDetachedEntity"
                value="true" />
              <!--<property name="openjpa.Log"
                value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />-->
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

For the sake of simplicity, persistence-unit "FleaCircus" is what I use ( Container Managed Persistence ). FleaCircusLocal is another test pu I created , where I've created a sample stateless bean that basically starts a new transaction, persist an element and commit it.
However it doesn't sinchronize immediatly and customer complains about it.

Is there any way to make OpenJPA makes whats in context immediatly visible to the DB or is it impossible due to the nature as OpenJPA/JPA was thought ?

For me it is not a big deal since data is visible inside the container ( Apache Geronimo ) however for the customer it is important since he wants to connet using 3rd party tool ( eg. SQL Developer to and see if data was inserted or not .)

Comment: _"data is visible inside the container"_ _"[the customer] wants to connet using 3rd party tool and see if data was inserted or not"_ You have to `commit` your changes for them to be visible from other transactions. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi Sylvain. Yes, when  dealing with transaction-type="JTA" , the container manages the transactions, however I've made an example using  RESOURCE_LOCAL PU ( started the transaction, persisted data and commited it ) however it doesn't appear on the database, only on apache datasource explorer. I think that data is only commited at the PersistenceContex and there is no way of immediatly telling JPA to insert data on the DB...

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted, basically I changed the datasource I've created o Apache Geronimo, and set the Transaction Type to "NONE" on Connection Pool parameters instead of "LOCAL" as I previously had. Setting as XA is not an option for my scenario since this is simply a web application made with Vaadin that communicates with database layer through EJB.

Comment: Congratulations to have solved your issue yourself ! Please, take some time to post your solution as a [self-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here. That will allow other peoples coming here from the Internet to see your solution.

Comment: small side note, you have OpenJPA2.2.x but persistence.xml sets JPA version=1.0 profile. I guess you have copypasted an old jpa tutorial file. Having version=2.0 is probably you wanted to use. See this https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager/blob/master/example_webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml